# Remove cart sidebar from page cache in magento

Tags: magento

My Customer website is enable with memcache, So when product is adding to the cart it's not able to calculate the discount (shopping cart rule) in mini cart (cart sidebar). So if I am refreshing the cache it's showing correctly. If anyone knows How to remove cart sidebar from caching (page cache) then please add comment.
Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. System > Configuration. Configuration Scope to Main Website
2. Go to Advanced > Disable module output > Mage_Checkout set to disabled

for more details log on http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/20853/